# Visual Studio Development Server using wrong port

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vs-devserver

Related to a [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/unable-to-launch-the-asp-net-development-server-because-port-1900-is-in-use) that I thought was resolved and actually isn't...

My Visual Studio 2008 installation may be a bit messed up, I think.

1. When my ASP.NET project is set up to use VS Dev Server with a fixed port, I get the "Port in use" error described in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/unable-to-launch-the-asp-net-development-server-because-port-1900-is-in-use).
2. When my project is set up to use a random (auto-assigned) port number, it works, but it launches the browser using a port number 3 less than the actual Dev Server port number (e.g. if the port number is 1903, the browser launches to http://localhost:1900/)
3. If I make changes to the project settings, they do not "take" until I save and restart Visual Studio.

Any ideas how to track this one down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I had a similar problem which hit my 2 main machines at the same time.  On investigating I found it to be related to the Eset personal security (guessing a recent update messed something up).  To solve it I excluded VS2008 from the active browser filtering - this is in:
setup -> advanced firewall setup -> antivirus & anti spyware -> web access protection -> HTTP -> webbrowsers

Deselecting vsdev in here fixed the problem - interestingly enough disabling the firewall and antivirus / antispyware did not solve the issue, so it is worth looking for a similar setting if you are running different security software

Comment: Aha!  I also have Eset!  We may be on the trail!

Comment: Indeed, it was Eset, and your instructions were spot on!  Congratulations, you got the bounty!

Comment: Thank you :) solved that strange problem from the first look too :)

Comment: It also worked for me, thanks, almost one day lost because of this issue

Comment: Macros - please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/unable-to-launch-the-asp-net-development-server-because-port-1900-is-in-use/650187#650187 and leave an answer there to claim credit for solving that one too.

Comment: Yet another firewall / security product causes more time lost and damage than the very thing they are there to protect.  ;)

Comment: Dear GOD this is why I love StackOverflow.  This was my problem exactly.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @ChrisLively: i dont think it causes damage in this regard, it is these loop holes that hackers exploit to get into your system I think the point is that this should have been properly documented and the enabling/disabling of apps in eset should be more reachable, thanks

Comment: i should say that some firewall programs also can cause this problem

Answer (score 17):

First try to kill all **"WebDev.WebServer.exe"** processes.

- In Solution Explorer, click the name of the application.
- In the Properties pane, click the down-arrow beside Use dynamic ports and select False from the dropdown list.This will enable editing of the Port number property.
- In the Properties pane, click the text box beside Port number and type in a port number.
- Click outside of the Properties pane. This saves the property settings.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

I do absolutely agree with Macros' answer. Just want to share solution for Eset Nod32 v5

In **ESET NOD32 v5** to allow Visual Studio to run Development or IIS Express server you must uncheck Visual Studio in Nod32 **Advanced Setup => Web and Email => Protocol filtering => Web and email clients**

Answer (score 2):

Weird!

The port number is stored in the .sln file.  So, I'd blow that away the solution file first, re-create it and see what happens.  If that doesn't help, I'd then move onto the web.config file and blow that away and start again too.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same error message:

> > Unable to launch Visual Studio development server because port [xxxx] is in use.

However, I do not have ESET installed. Instead, I had recently installed GlassFish server on my machine and that was causing the problem.  Therefore, in Windows Task Manager, I killed the process it runs under which is `java.exe` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This also applies to Visual Studio 2010.

And there is more to it.

Symptoms:

- A Web (Services) project is configured to run at a specific port, e.g. 10080.
- After a while Visual Studio compains “**Unable to launch the Visual Studio Development Server because port ’10080′ is in use**”
- The reason is still unclear. It might have something to do with the webdev server crashing.
- Restarting the pc doesn't solve the problem.
- Netstat doen’t show an entry for the port 10080
- Manually startin WebDev.WebServer40.exe at port 10080 works fine.

Since I'd like to start from within Visual Studio, I moved to port 10081, then to 10082, and today to 10083. I’m running out of ports.

**Solutions that did not work**:

- Restart Visual Studio
- Tweaking Trendmicro security settings (couldn't access them)
- Disabling Forticlient antivirus/firewall

**Workaround that DOES work**:

---

- Configuring my project to manually start the server
- Right click the project, choose properties
- Click the tab "Web"
- Pick for start action "**Start external program**" and point it to **Webdev.Webserver40.EXE**
  (for me: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.EXE)
- Command line arguments: **/port:10080 /path:C:\Solution\Project**
- Working directory: **C:\Solution\Project**
- Under servers check "**Use Custom Web Server**"
- Do not check any debugger checkbox

---

Side effect: my project *thinks* break points are not getting hit. ("no symbols loaded"). Turns out they work like they should.

I hope anybody ever finds a definitive solution, but up until then this workaround does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, just restart your PC. I've had the same problem, I did the same thing.

Comment: That most likely wouldn't solve the original problem of port numbers not lining up and not changing correctly. If a restart fixed something similar for you it was probably just multiple development server (Casini) instances running without shutting down correctly.