# Run Multiple Instance of application in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multiple-instances

Hi I have One Application when I run that It do some stuff with database.I want to run more then one instance of that application When try to run that applicaion again It gives me error like 'Unable to Launch ASP.NET Developoement Server Because Port is in use'.What is Solution for this?

Comment: Why you do need that? for debuging or in your production environment?

Comment: That sounds as if you're abusing ASP.NET as Windows-Service or Windows Application. Otherwise check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607562/visual-studio-development-server-using-wrong-port

Comment: @ivwiblo- I want to speed up the my work with using multple instances

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - Can We Do this with Windows Application???

Comment: @Hiren: What is _this_? Actually you havent't told anything about your requirement. It's certainly possible to use threading in a windows-service or in a winforms app. On the other side it's not clear at all if this would speedup your app.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter,You are right,I was abusing ASP.NET,I create windows application for my requirement,Thanks...