# Unable to launch the asp.net development server because port '80' is in use

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, networking

I need to use port 80 for my development server. Before i restart pc, it's still working fine. After that, it pop up the port 80 is in use. The development server able to run if i changed to other port.

I've checked using netstat -ano, no program is using it (my iis is using other port and my skype is not using port 80 as well).
I also test with telnet localhost 80, it didnt show any failure message, just the screen goes blank...I'm using win xp. Is my visual studio has problem?

Comment: You should consider marking some of your other questions as answered. It will encourage people to help you :)

Comment: Do you have Oracle on this machine?

Comment: No, i didnt have Oracle installed. But i have SQL2008 with it and i have turn off Integration and Reporting Services as i saw an article saying these two services will use port 80.

Comment: Were you using NOD32 antivirus??

Answer (score 2):

Things i have done.

1. Check it with netstat -ano and TcpView, both did not show port 80 is in use.
2. Try to connect it via telnet (telnet localhost 80). The screen goes blank, but when i press any key, the screen back to command prompt. As Lerxst said, screen goes blank meaning the port is occupied but i can't find any program is listening it.
3. I have skype installed, but it has turned off using port 80.
4. I have SQL 2008 installed, but i has turned off Integration & Reporting Services which may use port 80.
5. Changed my iis default port number to 8888 and even turn off the service.
6. I have XAMPP installed but i have turned off it.
7. I tried to turn off firewall as well, but still the same.

Comment: Another thing to check: I had the World Wide Web Publishing Service running (I don't remember having turned it on, but there it was) which sometimes won't show up with netstat -ano even though it does use port 80. I disabled that service since I wasn't needing it at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Skype, then Skype reserves port 80 as an alternative port (disable in Skype settings). I had this happening to me several times.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you've already disabled Skype at port 80. Try running TcpView from SysInternals to find the app to kill: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: Wow Fredrik - thanks for that last tip. I was able to see with TCPView (not netstat) that ccApp.exe was using port 1200. I Googled this and found it was part of Symantec antivirus so I stopped A/V, killed ccApp.exe and restarted A/V and I no longer had the port in use message. thanks a lot Claire

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is a reserved port number, for HTTP traffic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Why exactly do you *need* to use port 80?

Comment: I am using recaptcha with my project. When i create testing key for my recaptcha, it only can specify "http://localhost" without port number. If i using other port for my development server, i cannot test it locally. I can use port 80 before, so i suspect isnt that my visual studio has problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your telnet window goes blank when you telnet to 80, then something is already listening on that port.

Comment: But when i check it using netstat, it didn't show any program is listening it. And i tried to switch back my iis to port 80, it can listen too. Just my development server can't listen it

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and got two solutions for this:

- There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/unable-to-launch-the-asp-net-development-server-because-port-1900-is-in-use) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/unable-to-launch-the-asp-net-development-server-because-port-1900-is-in-use/12369779#12369779).
- What I tried is to change the port. For example: I was getting an error for port 22116, so I changed the port to 22117 and it started working.

Now how to do that:

1. In Solution Explorer, right click the name of the application.
2. Click on Properties menu.
3. In the left pan, click on the tab - Web
4. Here you can see a check box "Specific port" . (I just changed from 22116 to 22117)

For me, after this change it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to add a service reference to one of my projects. I deleted the service's site from my local IIS and re-created it from the service project in Visual Studio and re-built. This resolved the issue for me.