# Unable to lauch the ASP.NET development server as port '1115' is in use

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I got the above problem, Well as a daily routine  I switched on my PC, opened VS 2010, MS SQL Server. Build the solution and run it. I got this.

I googled it and i got these many solutions.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/unable-to-launch-the-asp-net-development-server-because-port-1900-is-in-use/12369779#12369779)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607562/visual-studio-development-server-using-wrong-port/655341#655341)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607562/visual-studio-development-server-using-wrong-port/641684#641684)

I tried to find the running process there are ain't one as i got the error when i run the application after i switched on my PC.

Every day it was working fine. Why not today?

I think i dont need to worry about firewall/antivirus. What may be the problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of Visual Studio running the same project? (Or 2 Copy of the project)

Comment: No i dont have multiple instances.

Comment: I've occasionally seen VS 2010 leave processes running even though you've told it to stop them.  A reboot should solve that (as well as a number of other possible issues).  If you're connecting to IIS, it gets even more complicated.

Comment: Try to change the port of IIS Express to something else, for example `30000`, and check if the problem remains. (Go to Project properties, Web tab, Project Url text box)

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt as Administrator and run the following to see what's listening on that port;

```
netstat -ab | more
```

Comment: No active connections on that port. I have checked it already

Comment: I just restrated my system, now the error is vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD Run As Administrator and run the below command:

> net stop hns && net start hns

above command is worked for me.!!